# Fabric js convert HTML code to IText

Tags: fabricjs

Is possible in [fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) convert this HTML code to an IText:

```
<p>Hello <strong>John!</strong></p>
```

I have read the docs, but I can't find anything...

I have tried with this with no results:

```
var text = canvas.add(new fabric.IText('<p>Hello <strong>John!</strong></p>', {}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in parser. You need to use text content of element and apply different styles using [styles](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#styles) property of [IText](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html).

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText('Hello John!', {
  fontSize: 20,
  styles: {
    0: {
      6: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      7: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      8: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      9: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      10: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
    }
  }
})
canvas.add(text);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<p>Hello <strong>John!</strong></p>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```