# Convert Html Code to Fabric Text Styles Attribute Dynamically

Tags: fabricjs

We can use rich text in fabric js with styles attribute like [Fabric js convert HTML code to IText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736806/fabric-js-convert-html-code-to-itext)

Example: `<p>Hello <strong>John!</strong></p>`

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText('Hello John!', {
  fontSize: 20,
  styles: {
    0: {
      6: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      7: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      8: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      9: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      10: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
    }
  }
})
canvas.add(text);
```

My purpose is to handle it dynamically with dynamic content. Is there any suggestion?